# Statistical Difference Between Multiple Groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

I would like to know if there is a statistical difference in the rate of different groups being routine or urgent.

My Data is as follows

```
Group.  Routine.       Urgent

A         361            79

B         297            41

C          38             4              

D          31             3

E          58            12
```

Would a Chi Square test work for this?

Comment: I guess this simpler approach could help you: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1471979/

Comment: Are those numbers counts? Are you interested in whether the proportion of urgent-whatevers differs across groups?

Comment: Hi Glen,  Yes those are number counts. Sorry, I should have been more clear.  And yes, I want to know if the proportion of urgent referrals differs across the different groups.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if there is a statistical difference in the rate of different groups being routine or urgent.

First, finding the rates:

```
prop.table(as.matrix(mydata),1) |> round(2)
    V2   V3
A 0.82 0.18
B 0.88 0.12
C 0.90 0.10
D 0.91 0.09
E 0.83 0.17
```

To see if the observed differences above are significant, or, maybe can be due to samplin errors, you can use a chi-squared test:

```r
chisq.test(mydata) 

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  mydata
X-squared = 7.434, df = 4, p-value = 0.1147
```

User @Lucas Farias hints at another method in a comment. I do not think that is correct for your case. That method, applied to each row in your table, test if rates for routine or urgent are equal ( so testing if both counts are about the same), while the chi-square test tests if rates (percentages) in each row are the same.

Code for reading data from post:

```r
textdata <- 
  "A 361 79

B 297 41

C 38 4

D 31 3

E 58 12" 

mydata <- read.table(textConnection(textdata), header=FALSE, row.names=1)
```